# How to get the following information to be written into a file in VConnect?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the following information to be written into a text file and can get it to work in my cPanel but not with VConnect. Have you guys used VConnect before?

I have tried changing the folder's name and have already set the permission to write in my folder called invoice but still can't get it to write in the folder.. everything else is working but just creating the file...

```
    <?php
include_once 'navbar.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process=notlogin");
    exit();
} else {
    include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $views = strip_tags($_POST['subscriptionplan']);
        $csrf = strip_tags($_POST['token']);

        if (!hash_equals($csrf, $_SESSION['token'])) {
            header("Location: medical_subscriptionplan.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process=wrongtoken");
          exit();
        } else {

        if ($views == '') {
            header("Location: medical_subscriptionplan.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process=emptied");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($views == '10_views') {
                $subscriptionplan = '10_views';
                $views = 10;
                $token = 'qqewreqreqwsdfdfdafcbvcQERFGHFGHGFHRETERTDF!@#$%^^()';
                $token = str_shuffle($token);
                $token = substr($token, 0, 10);
                $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $paidbydate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+2 day"));
                $fees = 5;

                $sql = "UPDATE memberships
                        SET subscriptionplan = ?, fees = ?, token = ?, enrollment_date = ?,                             paidbydate = ?, views = ?
                        WHERE user_uid = ?;

                       ";
                 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sisssis", $subscriptionplan, $fees,                             $token, $date, $paidbydate, $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                          $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                          echo $row['subscriptionplan'];
                          echo $row['enrollment_date'];
                          $myfile='invoice/10views'.$_SESSION['u_uid'].'.txt';

                                  if(file_exists($myfile)) {
                                     $invoice = "------------------------------------\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Level 1 Monthly Subscriptionplan Information\n"; 
                                $invoice .=  $level1."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Subscriptionplan:".$row['subscriptionplan']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Enrollment Date:".$row['enrollment_date']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Fees:".$row['fees']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Payment Status:".$row['paid']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Expiry Date:".$row['expirydate']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Payment Due Date:".$row['paidbydate']."\n"; 

                                $fh = fopen($myfile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
                                fwrite($fh, $invoice);
                                fclose($fh);
                                  } else {

                                  $invoice = "------------------------------------\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Level 1 Monthly Subscriptionplan Information\n"; 
                                $invoice .=  $level1."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Subscriptionplan:".$row['subscriptionplan']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Enrollment Date:".$row['enrollment_date']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Monthly Fees:".$row['fees']. "AUD\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Payment Status:".$row['paid']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Expiry Date:".$row['expirydate']."\n"; 
                                $invoice .= "Payment Due Date:".$row['paidbydate']."\n"; 

                                $myfile='invoice/10views'.$_SESSION['u_uid'].'.txt';
                                $fh = fopen($myfile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
                                fwrite($fh, $invoice);
                                fclose($fh);
                                  }

                      //    header("Location: medical_subscriptionplan.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process_10views=success");
                        } 
            } else {
        if ($views == '100_views') {
        $subscriptionplan = '100_views';
        $views = '100 views';
        $token = 'qqewreqreqwsdfdfdafcbvcQERFGHFGHGFHRETERTDF!@#$%^^()';
          $token = str_shuffle($token);
          $token = substr($token, 0, 10);
          $date = date("Y-m-d: H:i:s");
          $paidbydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 day"));
          $fees = 50;

        $sql3 = "UPDATE memberships
                        SET subscriptionplan = ?, fees = ?, token = ?, enrollment_date = ?, paidbydate = ?, views = ?
                        WHERE user_uid = ?;

               ";

         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sisssis", $subscriptionplan, $fees, $token, $date, $paidbydate, $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                          $premium = 1;
                          $sql4 = "UPDATE users
                                   SET premium = ?
                                   WHERE user_uid = ?

                                  ";

                           $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql4)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $premium, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                          header("Location: medical_subscriptionplan.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process_100views=success");
        }
        }  

    } else {
        if ($views == 'unlimited') {
                $subscriptionplan = 'unlimited';
        $views = -1;
          $token = 'qqewreqreqwsdfdfdafcbvcQERFGHFGHGFHRETERTDF!@#$%^^()';
          $token = str_shuffle($token);
          $token = substr($token, 0, 10);
          $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
          $paidbydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 day"));
          $fees = 500;

        $sql5 = "UPDATE memberships
                        SET subscriptionplan = ?, fees = ?, token = ?, enrollment_date = ?, paidbydate = ?, views = ?
                        WHERE user_uid = ?;

               ";

         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql5)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sisssis", $subscriptionplan, $fees, $token, $date, $paidbydate, $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                          $premium = 1;
                          $sql6 = "UPDATE users
                                   SET premium = ?
                                   WHERE user_uid = ?

                                  ";

                           $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql6)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $premium, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                           header("Location: medical_subscriptionplan.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process_unlimited_views=success");

}
        }
        }
    }
}
        }
        }
    }
}

/*

 } else {
        if ($views == '100_views') {
        $subscriptionplan = '100_views';
        $views = '100 views';
        $token = 'qqewreqreqwsdfdfdafcbvcQERFGHFGHGFHRETERTDF!@#$%^^()';
          $token = str_shuffle($token);
          $token = substr($token, 0, 10);
          $date = date("Y-m-d: H:i:s");
          $paidbydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 day"));
          $fees = 50;

        $sql3 = "UPDATE memberships
                        SET subscriptionplan = ?, fees = ?, token = ?, enrollment_date = ?, paidbydate = ?, views = ?
                        WHERE user_uid = ?;

               ";

         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sisssis", $subscriptionplan, $fees, $token, $date, $paidbydate, $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                          $premium = 1;
                          $sql4 = "UPDATE users
                                   SET premium = ?
                                   WHERE user_uid = ?

                                  ";

                           $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql4)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $premium, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            } else {
        if ($views == 'unlimited') {
                $subscriptionplan = 'unlimited';
        $views = -1;
          $token = 'qqewreqreqwsdfdfdafcbvcQERFGHFGHGFHRETERTDF!@#$%^^()';
          $token = str_shuffle($token);
          $token = substr($token, 0, 10);
          $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
          $paidbydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 day"));
          $fees = 500;

        $sql5 = "UPDATE memberships
                        SET subscriptionplan = ?, fees = ?, token = ?, enrollment_date = ?, paidbydate = ?, views = ?
                        WHERE user_uid = ?;

               ";

         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql5)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sisssis", $subscriptionplan, $fees, $token, $date, $paidbydate, $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                          $premium = 1;
                          $sql6 = "UPDATE users
                                   SET premium = ?
                                   WHERE user_uid = ?

                                  ";

                           $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql6)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $premium, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


        }
        }
    }
}





      } 
  } 


} 
}

}

}

}
header("Location: index.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process=sucess");
}
}
}
}
}


This is my updated code and everything is working with the database but I am trying to use $row here and got a boolean given error. If I don't use the $row variable, then it is fine....
```

Comment: You might get any errors. Have you seen php error log?

Comment: Could you try to reduce the problem to the relevant parts? Maybe reading the data from the DB is already broken?

Comment: I have included the code to display errors but nothing is showing.... I am trying to email to viewen because I don't get any error logs for vconnect.. the database is working.. just the create file

Comment: I got everything to work well but there seems to be an error when using $row.... I got a boolean error but my update query is correct though

Comment: If I don't use $row, then everything is inserting into the database fine

Comment: I have tried to echo the variables but it is empty....